# Yii2 database session - store additional attributes and user information

Tags: php, session, yii, yii2

I'm using Yii2's [DBSession](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-dbsession.html) class to store web application sessions into a database table, called `session`.

This table by default only has 3 columns - `id`, `expire` and `data`.

I'd like to store additional information into this table, like the `user_id` of a logged in user.

**Edit**: So there's a parent class called [yii\web\MultiFieldSession](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-multifieldsession.html) but no examples about how it's used. I'll see what I can discover...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

create migration:

```
$this->createTable('session', [
    'id' => $this->char(40)->notNull(),
    'expire' => $this->integer(),
    'data' => $this->binary(),
    'user_id' => $this->integer()
]);

$this->addPrimaryKey('session_pk', 'session', 'id');
```

add this to config:

```
'components' => [
    'session' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\DbSession',
        'writeCallback' => function($session){
            return [
                'user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id
            ];
        }
        // 'db' => 'mydb',  // the application component ID of the DB connection. Defaults to 'db'.
        // 'sessionTable' => 'my_session', // session table name. Defaults to 'session'.
    ],
```

Comment: Works great, thanks very much. I had the `writeCallback` function in a class extending `DbSession` and just couldn't get it working. Adding the function into the array like this works perfectly.

Comment: according documentation should be data MySQL: LONGBLOB, PostgreSQL: BYTEA, MSSQL: BLOB (https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-dbsession). For me MSSQL requires datatype nvarchar

Answer (score 0):

Check [writeCallBack](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-multifieldsession.html#$writeCallback-detail) (a callback that will be called during session data writing)

By Using callback you can set your own database fields.. Used by [composeField()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/web/MultiFieldSession.php#L96)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want a function in a config file, so I ended up with this:

`config/web.php`

```php
'components' =>
[
    'session' =>
    [
        'class' => 'app\models\Session',
    ],
],
```

`models/Session.php`

```php
class Session extends \yii\web\DbSession
{
    protected function composeFields($id = null, $data = null)
    {
        $fields = parent::composeFields($id, $data);

        $fields['user_id'] = \Yii::$app->user->id;

        return $fields;
    }
}
```